# How to get rid of repeating references in latex order of appearance?

Tags: cross-referencing, natbib, sorting

I am writing one of my article and when I am following citation I ended up with following issues. I want to follow the order of appearance in my citation. But when I am using one reference for the first time in the article in Chapter 1, it appears as follows,

[image]

When I am using the same reference again in Chapter 3, it appears as follows.

[image]

```
documentclass[12pt]{elsarticle}
usepackage[sorting=none]{natbib}
```

Do you have any idea how to get rid from this?

Thank you.

Comment: what is your question? you  show no code but if you reference the same thing twice obviously it gets the same number each timeí

Comment: In fact I need  a solution to get rid of the repeating reference no in the PDF but still keeping the order of appearance. For an example in the mentioned reference in the chapter 1 is [28],but when I am using again in chapter 3 with reference no [87] instead of [28].

Comment: that doesn't make sense. Or do you want to duplicate the references in the bibliography too, once under the number 28 and once under 87?

Comment: that would be truly weird and confusing for the reader. The number is the number of the entry in the list at the end of the document, so if you reference a work three times you put it three times in the list??? If you _really_ want that, do not use bibtex write a list of `\bibitem` by hand using a different key for each `\cite`